Can a capacitive touchscreen have configurable sensitivity?
I'm using a NHD-5.0-800480FT-CSXP-CTP display with capacitive touchscreen built-in. Here the datasheet.
I need to place the display behind a thin sheet of glass/plexiglass and I was looking for a way to tune the sensitivity of the touch (many smartphones have a "glove mode").
I was surprised to discover in the datasheet that such a setting exists for resistive version only. Instead, for the capacitive one I didn't find any related register.
Is this a limitation of the capacitive technology or is it just a technical choice of the manufacturer? Is there a way to improve the sensitivity of the touchscreen?
I read this question but it marginally refers to mine. In my case, a human being touches the screen. But if the default sensitivity is too low and I can't increase it in the controller, are there other ways to improve the usability? I.e. using "Pogo"s?
